# Why is the address of my pointer to first char of string != string address?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

Why is the address different if i print it from string "s" and from the first char of the string, saved in the pointer "p"? Should it not be the same? I get the same char but the address is different.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "hello";
    char *p = &s[0];
    printf("%p\n", s);
    printf("%p\n", p);

    printf("%c\n", s[0]);
    printf("%c\n", *p);
}
```

Comment: `std::string s` is not a `char s[x]` array.  For read-only access to a std:string's buffer use the .c_str(); method.  See: https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: `s` is not a pointer.  So `printf("%p",s)` is undefined.

Comment: And the address of a pointer cannot possibly be the same as the address of what it points to, unless it points to itself. Your question doesn't make sense. Also that's not what your code demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of plain C strings, where your pointers would match.

In a C++, the std::string is an object that contains the data (or more likely a pointer to it), so the object and the data it contains will be located in different places.